# How to fix bootstrap 4 modal not appear correctly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, navbar, fixed

When I clicked the button, the modal open perfectly, but I can't click the modal.

It seems modal is in behind some area. See this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You have tell us what you tried & share your code please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include a [mre]. That will let people see what the code is that is causing this and let them point out improvements to you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem came from z-index. I updated some code.
`.modal-backdrop{
        z-index: 1000;
    }`
now it fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Modal needs to be inside a container div, like this

```
<div class="container">
.
.
.
</div>
```

If no, the result is like your screenshot..

Maybe you forgot it, or accidentaly put it outside your container

Comment: Modal can be outside, it is just a matter of z-index